# Visual Studio Code show call hierarchy

Tags: visual-studio-code

Is there a function / shortcut, like <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>H</kbd> in WebStorm, to show the call hierarchy of a function in Visual Studio Code? If not, is there a plugin which does provide this feature? I'm looking for this feature for Typescript / JavaScript.

Comment: I changed callstack to call hierarchy, so that the question clear. If you know WebStorm, than I think the shortcut is clear enough. ;) So in the end the callstack is the same as the method hierarchy.

Comment: showing the call stack is not the same as me Ctrl + Alt + H or "Building Method Hierarchy".  https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/building-method-hierarchy.html

Comment: "Call Stack" has an entirely different meaning.

Answer (score 6):

In v1.43 see https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-docs/blob/vnext/release-notes/v1_43.md#call-hierarchy-support-for-javascript-and-typescript

> TypeScript 3.8 brings call hierarchy support in JavaScript and
>   TypeScript.

[image: call hierarchy support]

Comment: what does it mean "TypeScript 3.8 brings call hierarchy support"? Do I have to enable something in the settings? I'm working with a plain Javascript project and call hierarchy doesn't show callers.

Comment: See https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/88311#issuecomment-572292290 Typescript 3.8 was adopted in vscode v1.43 - until then you would have had to manually update your typescript version to use call hierarchy.  But you shouldn't have to do that now - assuming you are using vscode v1.43+.  It works for me.

Answer (score 4):

If I understood correctly it seems this is still a pending feature request https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/16110

Comment: In preview (but extensions need to implement) v1.33 see https://code.visualstudio.com/updates/v1_33#_call-hierarchy