# Call Hierarchy in Visual Studio Code

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

I'm trying to find a "View the Call Hierarchy" feature in Visual Studio/VSCodium.

What I want to do is right-click on a method's name (or press a keyboard shortcut), and a new pane opens up, displaying all the methods that call the clicked method, and the call tree of this method.

I found that in Eclipse and PyCharm but I only found "Find all references" in VSCode.

EDIT: I want to do that in Python, but if a such feature exists for all languages, that would be nice.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Visual Studio Code show call hierarchy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49197137/visual-studio-code-show-call-hierarchy)

Comment: I have (re-)opened this request: https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-python/issues/12945

Comment: I wonder if this feature is still in progress. I am looking for call heirarchy / call tree view for C/C++ functions in VsCode. This is a really helpful feature for programmers. I recently switched to VsCode after almost 10+ years using Eclipse IDE. We had this call heirarchy in Eclipse IDE that is super useful when it comes to understanding code flow. Could someone direct me if there are any free extensions available if VsCode doesn't support by its own?

Answer (score 34, accepted):

This is currently (v1.33) a preview feature. See [release notes re: call hierarchy](https://code.visualstudio.com/updates/v1_33#_preview-features).

> A call hierarchy view shows all calls from or to a function and allows
> you to drill into callers of callers and calls of calls. The image
> below shows that function foo is being called by bar and bang, then
> bar is being called by bang and fib.

[image: call hierarchy demo picture]

> This is a preview feature and there aren't any extensions currently
> providing real data for it. However, if you are an extension author,
> we invite you to validate our proposed API. If you are interested,
> there is a sample extension for testing:
> https://github.com/jrieken/demo-callhierarchy.

There is already a bound command for this, `editor.showCallHierarchy`.  You will have to see whether any python extension has support for this feature.

----------  Update  -------------------

v1.43 Release notes: https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-docs/blob/vnext/release-notes/v1_43.md#call-hierarchy-support-for-javascript-and-typescript

[image: call heirarchy]

---

In the v1.50 Insiders' Build is the ability to dismiss/exclude selected entries in the call heirarchy (possibly after you have reviewed that entry).  See https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/98155

Note the `X` dismiss button in the demo:

[image: call hierarchy dismiss demo]

[thanks to @VonC for finding this PR and pointing it out]

Comment: Could you please advice is there a shortcut that allow to open this view?

Comment: @SternK `Shift + Alt + H`

Comment: You might also update this very good answer with VSCode 1.50 PR https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/98155

Comment: @VonC  Thank you I have added the v1.50PR info to the answer.

Comment: I have version 1.52.0 and I still don't have this? Shift+Alt+H only opens up the help menu.

Comment: @JoeManiaci Perhaps you are using a language that doesn't support it yet?  Works in js/ts I know.

Comment: For those looking for a *call graph* for _TypeScript_ consider this project:
https://github.com/whyboris/TypeScript-Call-Graph

Comment: The OP wanted something that would work with python. The proposed solutions don't seem to be related to python.