# How to get the call stack of a Python library's function?

Tags: python, python-3.x, debugging, trace, stack-trace

I need to understand the code base of a relatively big Python library. The code being too convoluted, I thought it would be a good start to know which methods call which other methods when I execute an imported `function` that I need to use.

Is it possible to do something along the lines of:

```
from library import function
get_traceback(function)
```

And get a list of all the functions being called in the background by the library?

Comment: This is the kind of thing that's usually provided in a good IDE.

Comment: Is there a way to do this on vscode? I tried to "step into" the function in question but it doesn't go deep to the library level

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56008476/call-hierarchy-in-visual-studio-code