# Can't find 'Show Call Hierarchy' in VSCode

Tags: c++, visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

When I right click a function, there's no 'Show Call Hierarchy' or 'Peek Call Hierarchy'
option whatsoever. My popup menu looks like this

[image]

Then I tried Typing 'Show All Hierarchy' in command palette. This command does exist, but only gives a 'No Result' window after hitting enter.

So I went to Keyboard Shortcuts page, and it looks like this
[image]

My questions are,

1. Why can't I find 'Call Hierarchy' in popup menu while every tutorial online claims that I should have found it at this point.
2. What does 'When' field in Keyboard Shortcut page mean? Am I missing any 'CallHierarchyProvider'?

Addtional info:
VSCode version 1.60, having C/C++ and Emacs Keymap extensions installed. Tried VSCode on both MacOS and Ubuntu, issue remains the same. The code base I'm currently viewing is configured with CMake.

Any help is appreciated, thanks.

Comment: With the update frequency of modern software, all tutorials become partially obsolete in a matter of months, if not weeks.

Comment: @molbdnilo Not likely. VSCode devs said 'call hierarchy' gets supported in version 1.40 if I remember correctly. Cutting such a basic feature seems unresonable.

Comment: How it's enabled and accessed may well have changed since your tutorials were written, unless they are specifically about your version.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When a feature like that is added to VSCode release notes or any other documentation, you should assume that it is initially only available for JavaScript/TypeScript,

[Visual Studio Code show call hierarchy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49197137/visual-studio-code-show-call-hierarchy)

That's very commmon because VSCode is just an editor providing the infrastructure (context menus and other visual elements), but the actual language feature is provided by the individual language extensions and their language servers.

In your case, the C++ extension and its language server might fall far behind to support such features.

Answer (score 1):

For me, `clangd` vscode extension grants that capability and it seems integrated well enough to replace the basic intellisense. You will need to disable the default intellisense for that feature.

[image]

But as was mentioned here in the comments, "Show Hierarchy" support is listed in their backlog and expected to work with deafult c++ intellisense in the future.

It may be annoying to work with `clangd` while compiling with a `gcc` - some warnings and errors are not actually synced. This is very obvious with c++2a features support