# Is there "show call hierarchy" in VScode for Dart?

Tags: dart, visual-studio-code

Usually this is tied to the `ctrl`+`alt`+`h` keybind and available for many other languages but seems to be missing for dart. `Find references` provides only very basic functionality compared to call hierarchy.

P.S. I did see the SO answer [Visual Studio Code show call hierarchy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49197137/visual-studio-code-show-call-hierarchy) which is true for javascript but not dart.

Answer (score 2):

**Edit:** This was recently implemented in the Dart language server and will be included in a future Dart/Flutter SDK release.

--- Original Answer ---

The Dart extension/LSP Server does not currently provide an implementation of Call Hierarchy. It's something I did make a start on but hit some snags and haven't gotten back to resolving them yet.

There's an open issue you can subscribe to for updates on this feature here:

https://github.com/Dart-Code/Dart-Code/issues/612

Comment: It looks like it will be in Dart 2.19, due by Dec 7th 2022

Comment: Yep, this was implemented in https://github.com/dart-lang/sdk/commit/f34d4d5f93195eb6f30d3eb2ddcc1d34378dbba6. I've updated my answer. It should be included in the next major SDK releases - although, I don't think any dates have been published for them.